# What is the 'localization $X_x$' if $X$ is a scheme and $x \in X$ a point of $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, notation

I was reading the paper *Duality and Normalization* by Kollar and Dao ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.00042)) and I stumbled upon the notion and notation $X_x$ where $X$ is a scheme and $x \in X$ a point in some algebraic geometry paper where it was called the *localization*. I haven't met this notion and notation yet and I would like to know what its definition is and maybe some reference for this.

The context of the paper suggests that it is something like a direct limit $\varinjlim_{U \ni x} U$ over all open subschemes of $X$ containing $x$. I am grateful for any kind of hints and input.

Comment: It would be easier to give an answer to this if you included the title of the paper you were reading and where you saw this in said paper.

Comment: @KReiser It is *Duality and Normalization* by Janos Kollar, see here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.00042

It appears first on page 8, Lemma 27.

Comment: Isn't this $\operatorname {Spec} O_{X,x}$ ?

Answer (score 3):

This is just $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, which is exactly what you've written. If you want to check the equivalence yourself, you can see that both sides can be calculated along the open affine neighborhoods of $x$, and the direct limit of affine schemes corresponds to the colimit of their coordinate rings, which is exactly $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.